# HTTPD + mod_wsgi + Flask always gives "Not Found"

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I am new to flask and am trying to build a helloworld page with HTTPD + mod_wsgi.

**Configuration for httpd mod_wsgi**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/apps/org/orgda_dev/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/apps/org/orgda_dev/anaconda3"

WSGIScriptAlias / /apps/org/orgda_dev/webapp/orgdatools/helloworld.wsgi

<Directory /apps/org/orgda_dev/webapp/orgdatools>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Test configuration on standard mod_wsgi test code - success**

When the /apps/org/orgda_dev/webapp/orgdatools/helloworld.wsgi file contains below, I am able to see output generated by python @ http://hostname:8000
Basically this confirms the mod_wsgi is configured properly and running on root of website.

```
import sys

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = ('Hello World!' + sys.version).encode('utf-8') #  + sys.version
    # print >> environ['wsgi.errors'], "application debug #1"
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    # print >> environ['wsgi.errors'], "application debug #2"
    return [output]
```

**Issue with Flask app**

Always gives following error when I call http://hostname:8000

[image]

**Failing Flask app code mentioned below.**

Content of /apps/org/orgda_dev/webapp/orgdatools/helloworld.wsgi

```
from helloworld import app as application
```

Content of /apps/org/orgda_dev/webapp/orgdatools/helloworld.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

A few observations, I have:

- does not matter how I change decorator (and accordingly URL) it never works.
- There is no error in apache HTTPD error log
- In the log I can see python file getting executed (/apps/org/orgda_dev/webapp/orgdatools/helloworld.py)
- It seems apache HTTPD to wsgi to python URL transfer is not working
- Debug mode does not generate any output

After researching and trying for almost 8 hours, I am clueless how to move forward.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Since, you haven't specified any port for the Flask app, you wouldn't find anything at 'http://hostname:8000'. Either specify a different port no.(you cannot have the mod_wsgi and Flask listening to the same port) for the Flask app or launch Flask app without explicitly defining a port.

Comment: @amnab - My understanding is neither Flask nor mod_wsgi are listening on any port. Please see httpd.conf above. python interpreter is successfully called when I invoke the URL. I can see python code running by generated output in HTTPD log. The problem is method index() never gets executed.